# How to make Cucumber not erase database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

Everything running

```
rake cucumber feature/something
```

erases the database. Where in the env.rb or settings do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [seed](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html) files to populate your tables between test runs.

Comment: So you meaning adding to seed entries will not wipe my data?
Does cucumber fall back on seeds after running and not erase those entries? Before cucumber runs, there are entries. I need to have data entries after cucumber runs. I need something like populate entries after cucumber runs in the seed. Is that a good way?

Comment: Why do you want data to persist between test runs?